# Fit a conditional Bernoulli-gamma distribution using maximum likelihood

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, mixture-distribution

I am trying to model payment amounts for a collections agency. I am struggling with formulating the function I need to optimize, however. I have researched various distributions and stumbled-across the "Bernoulli-gamma" distribution which seems like a perfect fit to my data.

I understand the process for fitting a conditional logistic regression model using MLE where only one distribution parameter needs to be estimated. I am unclear how to apply the same principles to a distribution such as the one presented below where conditional estimates of the probability, shape, and scale parameters need to be estimated.

I have confused myself with everything I've read about today.

[image]

Edit:

My dataset consists of roughly 150 covariables describing the individuals in the debt portfolio. I have covariables regarding derogatory data such as bankruptcy and criminal behavior and non-derogatory variables such as education and voting registration.

The incidence rate of zeros is 90% for the entire file. My typical approach is to simply build a model predicting pay/no-pay using logistic regression. Therefore, the probability of paying nothing very much depends on these covariables.

My datasets vary in size from 10,000 observations to as many as 100,000 or more. I have tried building a two-stage model where the first stage is predicting pay or not and the send predicts the payment amount. I then multiply for the final prediction.  I have looked into the Heckit model which frames the problem as one of sample-selection bias.

But fitting a single model using MLE seems like a more elegant solution.

Comment: Which covariables do you have? What is the approximate value of probability of zero?  would that be approximately constant, or vary with some covariable? approximately, number of observations? Can you EDIT answers to these into the original post?

Comment: I have added further detail to my question.